# Weighing a baloon

Tags: mass, buoyancy

I know of methods of measuring the mass of a gas using chemistry, but this is unrelated. I was wondering if it is possible to deduce the mass of a helium balloon by measuring its mass it on a scale and somehow subtracting the buoyant force of the air to result in an accurate measurement?

Comment: hint - think upside down

Comment: I do not think that is a valid argument since a the same balloon filled with hydrogen instead of helium would show an even further negative value. That would imply that the hydrogen is more massive than the helium, which is not true. @MartinBeckett

Comment: It would show a more negative weight, ie more buoyant, ie less mass

Comment: @Ryan what do you mean by more massive? One atom of helium is definitely more massive than one atom of hydrogen?

Comment: @Ryan - The scale will show the buoyancy minus the weight. Since hydrogen weighs less than helium, the scale will show a greater force. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Set up a device to measure the upward pull of a helium balloon.  The upward pull in Newtons is the net buoyant force.  The net buoyant force is the weight of the displaced air, with the weight of the helium and the weight of the balloon subtracted from it.  Using the ideal gas law, calculate the weight of the displaced air and the weight of the helium.  This will give you enough information to calculate the mass of the balloon.

Comment: I think that the pressure difference between the inside and the outside of the balloon is not taken into account with this method.  However, I don't know if it is a significant source of error.

Comment: If you want extreme accuracy, take a second identical balloon, fill it to the same extent with helium, and put the (untied) end of the balloon on a precise pressure gauge.  The original questioner asked if it was possible to calculate the mass of a balloon from its buoyancy.  The answer is still a resounding "yes", and it is left to the experimenter to determine how precise and accurate his answer has to be.

Comment: Yes I agree.  Although if I had a second unfilled identical balloon, I would just weigh it.  ;P

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in theory, but there are challenges.  You need the mass of the empty balloon, which presumably you can measure before filling it with helium.  Then you need the volume of the inflated balloon, which you can measure by a 3D laser scanner.  Then if you allow for the volume occupied by the material of the balloon (which will be close to $1$ in specific gravity) you can do it.  The mass of helium is the measured weight (which will usually be negative) plus the weight of that volume of air (including the volume of the balloon) less the weight of the balloon, all divided by $g$